# how to get text box value in page init?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using asp.net 2.0

I set a hidden text box from javascript and on postback, i want to check the value stored on the text box in page init event. Here is what i tried

```
string t = Request.Form["currentMode"].ToString();
```

but i get an error saying " Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Any idea?asp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Init is the page life cycle where everything is initialized. You can't thrust that anything is availble. In order to do that you have to use the Page_Load event...

Comment: I added a Page_Load event could not find any other solution

Comment: You also shouldn't use the Request.Form collection. You should define your textbox with a serverside ID and use that ID in code to access the text property. E.g.: <asp:TextBox ID="NameTextbox" runat="server"> and in code then retrieve the text via: NameTextBox.Text

Answer (score 2):

In init the postback values have not been loaded into the controls yet, you could in theory fish the values from Request.Form variables, but they are named as the client ID of the controls.  If your controls are in any container like a contentplaceholder or detailsview they will have various guff prepended on the ID.  e.g. `ctl00$cphContentBody$txtMyTextbox` could be the id of a control that has a server side id of `txtMyTextbox`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the info but i could not utilize it without adding a page load event

Comment: That is a strange reponse. The page load event is the standard, natural place to access the properties of controls. The fact that you were trying to access these values in the init event made me assume that you had a good reason for doing so.  Aparently i was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this the other day while trying to build->submit->retrieve values from a dynamically created form (assembled during the Init() event of a postback). As Ben stated, you can use the `Request.Form` collection to pull out the values of the page's controls manually, using the `UniqueID` of the desired control (which will contain the "guff" Ben is talking about).

Of course, this is only necessary when trying to discover the value of a page's control before it is populated from viewstate (before LoadComplete). Otherwise, you could simply do something like `TextBox1.Text`.